# spork-testunit no tests run

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testunit, spork

New to Ruby so please bear with me... I am using JRuby on Windows, spork-0.9.0.rc9. I am able to use rake test fine but when I try with testunit using testdrb my tests are not run. For example:

```
testdrb -Itest test\functional\contents_controller_test.rb
Loaded suite contents_controller_test
Started

Finished in 0.113000 seconds.

0 tests, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
<-- Slave(2) run done!
```

Whereas using rake test:

```
>rake test TEST=test\functional\contentscontroller_test.rb
c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rack-1.3.4/lib/rack/backports/uri/common_192.rb:53 warning: already initialized constant WFKV
Loaded suite c:/dev/apps/jruby-1.6.4/lib/ruby/gems/1.8/gems/rake-0.9.2/lib/rake/rake_test_loader
Started

ContentsControllerTest:
PASS should create content (0.19s)
PASS should destroy content (0.03s)
PASS should get edit (0.29s)
PASS should get index (0.22s)
PASS should get new (0.06s)
PASS should show content (0.04s)
PASS should update content (0.05s)

Finished in 0.880000 seconds.

7 tests, 17 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Comment: Did you solve this? I have the same problem.

Comment: Nope, switched to rspec, I like it better anyway :)